# Can't run Scrapy program

Tags: python, module, web-crawler, scrapy

I have been learning how to work with Scrapy from the following link :

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/master/intro/tutorial.html

When i try to run the code written in the Crawling(`scrapy crawl dmoz`) section, i get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Spider`'

However, i changed "Spider" to "spider" and i got nothing but a new error:

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I'm so confused, what is the problem? Any help would highly be appreciated. Thanks. By the way, i am using Windows.

EDIT(source added):

First i created a project using Scrapy by going to a directory and running the following commands by cmd like so :

```
cd #DIRECTORY PATH#

scrapy startproject tutorial
```

This will create a folder named tutorial in the given directory. The tutorial folder consists :

tutorial/
    scrapy.cfg
    tutorial/
        **init**.py
        items.py
        pipelines.py
        settings.py
        spiders/
            **init**.py
            ...

Then i defined my items :

```
import scrapy

class DmozItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    desc = scrapy.Field()
```

Afterwards, i created the spider:

import scrapy

```
class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

And after, when running the code,the error is shown. I am using windows 7 64 bit along with Python 2.7 32 bit.

EDIT 2:

I tried uninstalling and installing another Scrapy version but it didn't work. Here is the log:

```
C:\Users\Novin Pendar\Desktop\FS\tutorial>scrapy crawl dmoz
2015-03-26 17:48:29+0430 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.16.5 started (bot: tutorial)
2015-03-26 17:48:29+0430 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetCon
sole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.16.5-py2.7.egg\scrapy\__init__.pyc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.16.5-py2.7.egg\scrapy\cmdline.py"
, line 156, in <module>
    execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.16.5-py2.7.egg\scrapy\cmdline.py"
, line 131, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.16.5-py2.7.egg\scrapy\cmdline.py"
, line 76, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.16.5-py2.7.egg\scrapy\cmdline.py"
, line 138, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.16.5-py2.7.egg\scrapy\commands\cr
awl.py", line 43, in run
    spider = self.crawler.spiders.create(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.16.5-py2.7.egg\scrapy\command.py"
, line 33, in crawler
    self._crawler.configure()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.16.5-py2.7.egg\scrapy\crawler.py"
, line 40, in configure
    self.spiders = spman_cls.from_crawler(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.16.5-py2.7.egg\scrapy\spidermanag
er.py", line 35, in from_crawler
    sm = cls.from_settings(crawler.settings)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.16.5-py2.7.egg\scrapy\spidermanag
er.py", line 31, in from_settings
    return cls(settings.getlist('SPIDER_MODULES'))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.16.5-py2.7.egg\scrapy\spidermanag
er.py", line 22, in __init__
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.16.5-py2.7.egg\scrapy\utils\misc.
py", line 65, in walk_modules
    submod = __import__(fullpath, {}, {}, [''])
  File "tutorial\spiders\dmoz_spider.py", line 3, in <module>
    class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Spider'
```

EDIT 3:

The problem is solved. I downloaded the latest version of Scrapy(0.24) and installed. Everything worked so great. Just wanted to say to people who have the same problem that i used to, so, they will save them a lot of time. Thanks.

Comment: Please check the code you've written. If it's exactly the same as what's in the tutorial, please post what you've written here and someone can debug it for you.

Comment: How did you install scrapy?

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim: I tried to install it with distutils but after getting an unknown error, i tried installing it with pip.

Answer (score 1):

If your installation is correct.Try this

Check any `scrapy.py` or `scrapy.pyc`, in the working folder.If exists, rename it.Dont change `Spider` to `spider`

Comment: None of either files you said are in working directory. Thanks.

Comment: Then print  `scrapy.__file__` after `import scrapy`

Comment: Here is the output : C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.22.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\__init__.pyc

What does that code mean?

Comment: check `print(dir(scrapy))` and check whether `Spider` is present in that list.Otherwise check with `scrapy.spider.Spider` or `scrapy.scrapy.Spider` instead of `scrapy.Spider`.This is for assuming if any change in other versions.

Answer (score 0):

use this definition:
class DmozSpider(scrapy.spider.BaseSpider):