# Getting an error on importing Scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

Getting this error on importing scrapy:

```
AttributeError: module 'scrapy' has no attribute 'Spider'
```

I've read this post **[Can't run Scrapy program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275958/cant-run-scrapy-program)** but still confused because i've uninstalled and installed scrapy twice but still getting same error and the mentioned post's discussion is making me confuse. for the first time when i installed srapy and import scrapy it was working fine. But after sometime it started to give me this error.

[Error on cmd_Screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnVxH.jpg)

**Edited:**
on checking version i'm getting this stack trace:

```
C:\Users\hadi>scrapy version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\hadi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\hadi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\hadi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\scrapy.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\hadi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\scrapy.py", line 3, in <module>
    class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
AttributeError: module 'scrapy' has no attribute 'Spider'
```

Solved it by myself tried installation through miniconda. Thanks BTW

Comment: What version of `scrapy` are you using?

Comment: whenever i used to run command for scrapy version it gives me error of same as above

Comment: version is Scrapy-1.5.0